# sed couldn't flush stdout no space left on device?

Tags: linux, sed

What could be the reason for this error :

```
sed couldn't flush stdout no space left on device
```

This is come of the stuff that i am doing at last in my code

```
sed -n '/.*needs to be executed manually.*/{n;p}' "$ERR_LOG"*

sed -n '/.*have.*latest.*/{n;p}' "$ERR_LOG"* >> "$ERR_LOG"final.log


sed -n '/.*Phone type not recognised.*/p' "$ERR_LOG"* >> "$ERR_LOG"final.log


sed '/.*#/!{H;d;}
x;/\n.*Error/!d' "$ERR_LOG"* >> "$ERR_LOG"final.log


sed '/.*#/!{H;d;}
x;/\n%/!d' "$ERR_LOG"* >> "$ERR_LOG"final.log
```

sed is seraching through around 10 - 15 files of size=50-69 kb (approx)

**EDIT 1** : This is the exact error :

```
sed: couldn't write 166 items to stdout: No space left on device
sed: couldn't write 201 items to stdout: No space left on device
All the hostnames processed
sed: couldn't flush /home/gocs1/LOG//sed6hkHBu: No space left on device
sed: couldn't flush /home/gocs1/LOG//sedM2dr4u: No space left on device
sed: couldn't flush /home/gocs1/LOG//sed6A8NWu: No space left on device
sed: couldn't flush /home/gocs1/LOG//sedbmkv3x: No space left on device
sed: couldn't flush /home/gocs1/LOG//sed42pjSx: No space left on device
sed: couldn't flush /home/gocs1/LOG//sedMKxrHy: No space left on device
Time Taken :
0 hour(s) 58 minute(s) 33 second(s)
```

what does this mean.

```
  /home/gocs1/LOG//sed6hkHBu
```

i have created the directory upto `/home/gocs1/LOG/` but the rest(`/sed6hkHBu`) is not created by me.

**EDIT 2** : does `sed` or `sed -i` option creates files in tmp directory i had many files 
created in `/tmp/LOG` directory with one file of huge size(800 MB) also while the script was running.

Comment: This generally happens when the filesystem you are writing STDOUT to is out of space. What is the output of `df -h`?

Comment: i checked the home directory of the person using it by `df .` and i could see used space was about 5%.I am not in front of the server right now but i will try to give more details within minute.

Comment: also check inode usage with `df -i`. in case you're out of inode, you'll get the same "out of space" message.

Comment: sounds like full /tmp for me.

Comment: i dont inode was full when the my script ran but  LOG directory was created along with many files in it in `/tmp/LOG`

Comment: What does your last comment mean? You don't what? Does "inode was full" mean there were no free inodes left?

Comment: no inode was not full inodes used are like 1% 2% 3% only

Comment: Are there any symlinks in that path? Try `cd /home/gocs1/LOG/; pwd -P` to ensure that you are still inside the home directory.

Comment: this is what i got `[user@hostname]$ cd /home/gocs1/LOG/; pwd -P` output : `/home/gocs1/LOG `