# sed in-place line deletion on full filesystem?

Tags: text-processing, files, sed, ed

Due to an application bug as yet undiagnosed, I have several hundred servers with a full disk.  There is one file that has been filled up with duplicate lines—not a log file, but a user environment file with variable definitions (so I can't just delete the file).

I wrote a simple `sed` command to check for the erroneously added lines and delete them, and tested it on a local copy of the file.  It worked as intended.

However, when I tried it on the server with the full disk, I got approximately the following error (it's from memory, not copy and paste):

```
sed: couldn't flush /path/to/file/sed8923ABC: No space left on deviceServerHostname
```

Of course, I *know* there's no space left.  That's why I'm trying to delete stuff!  (The `sed` command I'm using will reduce a 4000+ line file to about 90 lines.)

My `sed` command is just `sed -i '/myregex/d' /path/to/file/filename`

Is there a way I can apply this command despite the full disk?

(It must be automated, since I need to apply it to several hundred servers as a quick-fix.)

<sub>(Obviously the application bug needs to be diagnosed, but in the meantime the servers aren't working correctly....)</sub>

---

**Update:** The situation I faced was resolved by deleting something else that I found out I could delete, but I'd still like the answer to *this* question, which would be helpful in the future and for other people.

`/tmp` is a no-go; it's on the same filesystem.

Before I freed up disk space, I did test and find out that I could delete the lines in `vi` by opening the file and running `:g/myregex/d` and then successfully save the changes with `:wq`.  It seems it should be possible to automate this, without resorting to a separate filesystem to hold a temp file....  (?)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75889/135943

Comment: For the astute readers wondering how I'm using a `sed` *regex* to check for *duplicate* lines:  Good spotting; I'm really not checking for *duplicate* lines.  The lines that should stay in the file all use double quotes around the values; the lines that should be deleted all use single quotes.

Comment: `sponge` of `moreutils` fame might be able to schlep the data off to `/tmp` or perhaps a memory filesystem as a workaround to the partition being full.

Comment: `sed -i` creates a temporary copy to operate on.  I suspect that `ed` would be better for this, though I'm not familiar enough to proscribe an actual solution

Comment: With `ed` you'd run: `printf %s\\n g/myregex/d w q | ed -s infile` but keep in mind some implementations also use temporary files just like `sed` (you could try _busybox ed_  - afaik it doesn't create a temporary file)

Comment: your `vi` success was probably only a success because you had the memory to handle it. a similar thing might be done with `sed` like: `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;P' <file | { read v&& sed "$script" >file; }`

Comment: @mikeserv, interesting point that it is only sufficient memory that allowed me to do that...so then (except for trailing newlines which would be stripped) I could probably have done it with `echo "$(sed '/myregex/d' file)" > file`?

Comment: @Wildcard - not reliably w/ `echo`. use `printf`. and make `sed` append some char you drop at the last line so you can avoid losing trailing blanks. also, your shell needs to be able to handle the whole file in a single command-line. that's your risk - test first. `bash` is especially bad at that *(i think its to do w/ stack space?)* and may sick up on you at any time. the two `sed`'s i recommended would at least use the kernel's pipe buffer to good effect between them, but the method is fairly similar. your command sub thing will also truncate `file` whether or not the sed w/in is successful.

Comment: @Wildcard - try `sed '/regex/!H;$!d;x' <file|{ read v && cat >file;}` and if it works read the rest of my answer.'

Answer (score 11):

The `-i` option doesn't really overwrite the original file. It creates a new file with the output, then renames it to the original filename. Since you don't have room on the filesystem for this new file, it fails.

You'll need to do that yourself in your script, but create the new file on a different filesystem.

Also, if you're just deleting lines that match a regexp, you can use `grep` instead of `sed`.

```
grep -v 'myregex' /path/to/filename > /tmp/filename && mv /tmp/filename /path/to/filename
```

In general, it's rarely possible for programs to use the same file as input and output -- as soon as it starts writing to the file, the part of the program that's reading from the file will no longer see the original contents. So it either has to copy the original file somewhere first, or write to a new file and rename it when it's done.

If you don't want to use a temporary file, you could try caching the file contents in memory:

```
file=$(< /path/to/filename)
echo "$file" | grep -v 'myregex' > /path/to/filename
```

Comment: Did it preserves permissions, ownership and timestamps? Maybe `rsync -a --no-owner --no-group --remove-source-files "$backupfile" "$destination"` from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131266)

Comment: @Hastur - do you mean to imply that `sed -i` does preserve that stuff?

Comment: @Hastur `sed -i` doesn't preserve any of those things. I just tried it with a file I don't own, but located in a directory that I do own, and it let me replace the file. The replacement is owned by me, not the original owner.

Comment: @Barmar - that's what i thought. `sed -i` or `perl -i` are both seriously insecure and I've always considered their popularity confusing. actually writing over the file is the only sure way to do it. creating a new file and moving it over the old results in *a new file*.

Comment: What about `echo "$(cat FILE)" | grep '^"' > FILE`? I'm guessing that would capture FILE in RAM before renewing it.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist - maybe - if `cat` can open `FILE` and if the shell can handle the length of the resulting command... Probably not, though, if the shell sets up the pipeline starting at the right side, or if the subshell spawned on the right-side winds up coming around sooner than the one opened on the left. In either of those cases *(which are fairly likely to occur)* the subshell on the right side truncates FILE before the one on the left opens it and reads it, or perhaps it truncates it while the command sub reads it. See my answer here for how to overwrite a file in place.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist To be sure, you'd need to do it in two steps: `var=$(< FILE); echo "$FILE" | grep '^"' > FILE`

Comment: @Barmar - how is that sure? you don't test anything.

Comment: @mikeserv When commands are separated by a semicolon, the first one completes before the second one begins. So there can't be any interference. I don't need to test this to know it's true.

Comment: i know how it works - but you dont test anything - it could be an empty variable. you dont know if it worked - you just echo.

Comment: Why would it be an empty variable? I just assigned it from the output of a command that I know works.

Comment: Just notices a typo, I meant `echo "$var"`. I got it right in my edit of the answer.

Comment: @Barmar - you don't it works - you don't even know you've successfully opened input. The *very* least you could do is `v=$(<file)&& printf %s\\n "$v" >file` but you don't even use `&&`. The asker's talking about running it in a script - automating overwriting a file with a portion of itself. you ought at least to validate you can successfully open input and output. Also, the shell might explode.

Comment: This is a very good answer, actually; it hadn't occurred to me to place it in a variable.  Also, @mikeserv is right: for automating this, I would *definitely* not run it without `&&`.

Answer (score 4):

That's how `sed` works. If used with `-i` (in place edit) `sed` creates a temporary file with the new contents of the processed file. When finished `sed`, replaces the current working file with the temporary one. The utility does not edit the file *in-place*. That's exact the behavior of every editor.

It's like you perform the following task in a shell:

```
sed 'whatever' file >tmp_file
mv tmp_file file
```

At this point `sed`, tries to flush the buffered data to the file mentioned in the error message with the `fflush()` system call:

> For output streams, `fflush()` forces a write of all user-space
>   buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's
>   underlying write function.

---

For your problem, I see a solution in mounting a separte filesystem (for instance a `tmpfs`, if you have enough memory, or an external storage device) and move some files there, process them there, and move them back.

Answer (score 3):

Since posting this question I've learned that `ex` is a POSIX-compliant program.  It's almost universally symlinked to `vim`, but either way, the following is (I think) a key point about `ex` in relation to filesystems (taken from the POSIX specification):

> This section uses the term *edit buffer* to describe the current working text. No specific implementation is implied by this term. All editing changes are performed on the edit buffer, and no changes to it shall affect any file until an editor command writes the file.

"...shall affect **any** file..."  I believe that putting something on the filesystem (at all, even a temp file) would count as "affecting any file."  Maybe?*

Careful study of the [POSIX specifications for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) indicate some "gotchas" about its intended portable use when compared to common scripted uses of `ex` found online (which are littered with `vim`-specific commands.)

1. Implementing `+cmd` is optional according to POSIX.
2. Allowing multiple `-c` options is also optional.
3. The global command `:g` "eats" everything up to the next non-escaped newline (and therefore runs it after each match found for the regex rather than once at the end).  So `-c 'g/regex/d | x'` only deletes *one* instance and then exits the file.

So according to what I've researched, **the POSIX-compliant method for in-place editing a file on a full filesystem to delete all lines matching a specific regex, is:**

```
ex -sc 'g/myregex/d
x' /path/to/file/filename
```

This should work providing you have sufficient memory to load the file into a buffer.

<sub>*If you find anything which indicates otherwise, please, mention it in the comments.</sub>

Comment: but ex writes to tmpfiles... always. its spec'd to write its buffers to disk periodically. there are even spec'd commands for locating the tmp file buffers on disk.

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks for sharing, I've linked back at [similar post at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33186317/55075). I assume `ex +g/match/d -scx file` is POSIX-compliant as well?

Comment: @kenorb, not quite, according to my reading of the specs—see my point 1 in the answer above.  Exact quote from POSIX is "The ex utility shall conform to XBD Utility Syntax Guidelines, except for the unspecified usage of '-', and that **'+' *may* be recognized** as an option delimiter as well as '-'."

Comment: I can’t prove it, except by appeal to common sense, but I believe that you’re reading more into that statement from the specification than is really there.  I suggest that the safer interpretation is that no changes to the edit buffer shall affect any file that existed before the edit session began, or that the user named.  See also my comments on my answer.

Comment: @G-Man, I actually think you're right; my initial interpretation was probably wishful thinking.  However, since editing the file in `vi` *worked* on a full filesystem, I believe that in *most* cases it would work with `ex` as well—though maybe not for a ginormous file.  `sed -i` doesn't work on a full filesystem regardless of filesize.

Answer (score 2):

*Use the pipe, Luke!*

Read file | filter | [write back](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place/11074#11074)

```
sed 's/PATTERN//' BIGFILE | dd of=BIGFILE conv=notrunc
```

in this case `sed` doesn't create a new file and just send output piped to `dd` which opens *the same file*. Of course one can use `grep` in particular case

```
grep -v 'PATTERN' BIGFILE | dd of=BIGFILE conv=notrunc
```

then [truncate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/how-can-i-edit-a-large-file-in-place/1305#1305) the remaining.

```
dd if=/dev/null of=BIGFILE seek=1 bs=BYTES_OF_SED_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Did you notice the **"full filesystem"** part of the question?

Comment: @Wildcard , does `sed` always use temp files?  `grep` anyway won't

Comment: This seems an alternative to [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) command. Yes, `sed` with `-i` always creates files lilke "seduyUdmw" with 000 rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the file quite easily if you can get the byte count to your offset and your lines occur from a start point through to the end.

```sh
o=$(sed -ne'/regex/q;p' <file|wc -c)
dd if=/dev/null of=file bs="$o" seek=1
```

---

Or else if your `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` is on some other file system perhaps:

```sh
{   cut -c2- | sed "$script" >file
} <file <<FILE
$(paste /dev/null -)
FILE
```

Because *(most)* shells put their here-documents there in a deleted temp-file. It is perfectly safe so long as the `<<FILE` descriptor is maintained from start to finish and `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` has as much space as you need.

Shells which don't use temp files use pipes, and so are not safe to use this way. These shells are typically *`ash`* derivatives like `busybox`, `dash`, BSD `sh` - `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, and the Bourne shell, however, all use temp files.

*apparently I [wrote a little shell program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218144/52934) last July to do something very like this*

---

If `/tmp` is not viable, then so long as you can fit the file in memory something like...

```sh
sed 'H;$!d;x' <file | { read v &&
sed "$script" >file;}
```

...as a general case would at least ensure that the file was fully buffered by the first `sed` process before attempting to truncate the in/out file.

A more targeted - and efficient - solution could be:

```sh
sed '/regex/!H;$!d;x' <file|{ read v && cat >file;}
```

...because it wouldn't bother buffering lines you meant to delete anyway.

A test of the general case:

```sh
{   nums=/tmp/nums
    seq 1000000 >$nums
    ls -lh "$nums"
    wc -l  "$nums"
    sed 'H;$!d;x' <$nums | { read script &&  ### read always gets a blank
    sed "$script" >$nums;}
    wc -l  "$nums"
    ls -lh "$nums"
}
```

---

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 6.6M Dec 22 20:26 /tmp/nums
1000000 /tmp/nums
1000000 /tmp/nums
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 6.6M Dec 22 20:26 /tmp/nums
```

Comment: I confess I hadn't read your answer in detail before, because it starts with unworkable (for me) solutions that involve byte count (different amongst each of the many servers) and `/tmp` which is on the same filesystem.  I like your dual `sed` version.  I think a combination of Barmar's and your answer would probably be best, something like: **`myvar="$(sed '/myregex/d' < file)" && [ -n "$myvar" ] && echo "$myvar" > file ; unset myvar`**  (For this case I don't care about preserving trailing newlines.)

Comment: @Wildcard - that could be. but you shouldnt use the shell like a database. the `sed` | `cat` thing above *never* opens output unless `sed` has already buffered the entire file and is ready to start writing all of it to output. If it tries to buffer the file and fails - `read` is not successful because finds EOF on the `|` pipe *before* it reads its first newline and so `cat >out` *never happens* until its time to write it out from memory entirely. an overflow or anything like it just fails. also the whole pipeline returns success or failure every time. storing it in a var is just more  risky.

Comment: @Wildcard - if i *really* wanted it in a variable too, i think id do it like: `file=$(sed '/regex/!H;$!d;x' <file | read v && tee file) && cmp - file <<<"$file" || shite` so the output file and the var would be written simultaneously, which would make either or an *effective* backup, which is the only reason you'd wanna complicate things further than you'd need to.

Comment: @mikeserv: I am dealing the same problem as the OP now and I find your solution really useful. But I don't understand the usage of `read script` and `read v` in your answer. If you can elaborate more about it I will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @sylye - `$script` is the `sed` script you would use to target whatever portion of your file you wanted; its the script that gets you the end result that you want in stream. `v` is just a placeholder for an empty line. in a `bash` shell it is not necessary because `bash` will automatically use the `$REPLY` shell variable in its stead if you dont specify one, but POSIXly you should always do so. im glad you find it useful, by the way. good luck with it. im mikeserv@gmail if you need anything in depth. i should have a computer again in a few days

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other answers,
`sed -i` works by copying the file to a new file *in the same directory*,
making changes in the process, and then moving the new file over the original. 
That's why it doesn't work. 
`ed` (the original line editor) works in a somewhat similar manner,
but, last time I checked, it uses `/tmp` for the scratch file. 
If your `/tmp` is on a different filesystem from the one that's full,
`ed` may do the job for you.

Try this (at your interactive shell prompt):

```
$ ed /path/to/file/filename
P
g/myregex/d
w
q
```

The `P` (which is a *capital* P) is not strictly necessary. 
It turns on prompting; without it, you're working in the dark,
and some people find this disconcerting. 
The `w` and `q` are **w**rite and **q**uit.

> `ed` is notorious for cryptic diagnostics. 
>   If at any point it displays anything other that the prompt (which is `*`)
>   or something that is clearly a confirmation of successful operation
>   (*especially* if it contains a `?`), ***do not*** write the file (with `w`). 
>   Just quit (`q`).  If it doesn't let you out, try saying `q` again.

If your `/tmp` directory is on the filesystem that is full (or if its filesystem is full, also), try to find some space somewhere. 
chaos mentioned mounting a tmpfs or an external storage device
(e.g., a flash drive);
but, if you have multiple filesystems, and they are not *all* full,
you can simply use one of the other existing ones. 
chaos suggests copying the file(s) to the other filesystem,
editing them there (with `sed`), and then copying them back. 
At this point, that may be the simplest solution. 
But an alternative would be to create a writable directory
on a filesystem that has some free space,
set environment variable `TMPDIR` to point to that directory,
and then run `ed`. 
(Disclosure: I'm not sure whether this will work, but it can't hurt.)

Once you get `ed` working, you can automate this by doing

```
ed filename << EOF
g/myregex/d
w
q
EOF
```

in a script.  Or
`printf '%s\n' 'g/myregex/d' w q | ed -s filename`,
as suggested by don_crissti.

Comment: Hmmm.  Can the same thing be done (either with `ed` or with `ex`) such that *memory* is used rather than a separate filesystem?  That's what I was really going for (and the reason I haven't accepted an answer.)

Comment: Hmm.  This may be more complicated than I realized.  I studied the source of `ed` extensively many years ago.  There were still such things as 16-bit computers, on which processes were limited to a 64K (!) address space, so the idea of an editor reading the entire file into memory was a non-starter.  Since then, of course, memory has gotten bigger — but so have disks and files.  Since disks are so big, people don’t feel a need to deal with the contingency of `/tmp` running out of space.  I just took a quick look at the source code of a recent version of `ed`, and it still seems  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  to implement the “edit buffer” as a temp file, unconditionally — and I cannot find any indication that any version of `ed` (or `ex` or `vi`) offers an option to keep the buffer in memory.  ***On the other hand,*** [Text Editing with ed and vi – Chapter 11: Text Processing – Part II: Exploring Red Hat Linux – Red Hat Linux 9 Professional Secrets – Linux systems](http://etutorials.org/Linux+systems/red+hat+linux+9+professional+secrets/Part+II+Exploring+Red+Hat+Linux/Chapter+11+Text+Processing/Text+Editing+with+ed+and+vi) says that `ed`’s edit buffer resides in memory,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and [UNIX Document Processing and Typesetting by Balasubramaniam Srinivasan](https://books.google.com/books?id=uKHsCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA373&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) says the same thing about `vi` (which is the same program as `ex`).  I believe that they’re just using sloppy, imprecise wording — but, if it’s on the Internet (or in print), it must be true, right?  You pay your money and you take your choice.

Comment: But anyway, I’ve added a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer borrows ideas from [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251003/80216)
and [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255589/80216) but builds on them,
creating an answer that is more generally applicable:

```
num_bytes=$(sed '/myregex/d' /path/to/file/filename | wc -c)
sed '/myregex/d' /path/to/file/filename 1<> /path/to/file/filename
dd if=/dev/null of=/path/to/file/filename bs="$num_bytes" seek=1
```

The first line runs the `sed` command with output
written to standard output (and not to a file);
specifically, to a pipe to `wc` to count the characters. 
The second line also runs the `sed` command with output
written to standard output,
which, in this case is redirected to the input file
in read/write overwrite (no truncate) mode,
which is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/80216). 
This is a somewhat dangerous thing to do; it is safe only
when the filter command *never* increases the amount of data (text);
i.e., for every *n* bytes that it reads, it writes *n* or fewer bytes. 
This is, of course, true for the `sed '/myregex/d'` command;
for every line that it reads, it writes the exact same line, or nothing. 
(Other examples: `s/foo/fu/` or `s/foo/bar/` would be safe,
but `s/fu/foo/` and `s/foo/foobar/` would not.)

For example:

```
$ cat filename
It was
a dark and stormy night.
$ sed '/was/d' filename 1<> filename
$ cat filename
a dark and stormy night.
night.
```

because these 32 bytes of data:

```
I  t     w  a  s \n  a     d  a  r  k     a  n  d     s  t  o  r  m  y     n  i  g  h  t  . \n
```

got overwritten with these 25 characters:

```
a     d  a  r  k     a  n  d     s  t  o  r  m  y     n  i  g  h  t  . \n
```

leaving the seven bytes `night.\n` left over at the end.

Finally, the `dd` command seeks to the end of the new,
scrubbed data (byte 25 in this example) and removes the rest of the file;
i.e., it truncates the file at that point.

---

If, for any reason, the `1<>` trick doesn’t work, you can do

```
sed '/myregex/d' /path/to/file/filename | dd of=/path/to/file/filename conv=notrunc
```

---

Also, note that, as long as all you’re doing is removing lines,
all you need is `grep -v myregex` (as pointed out by [Barmar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251001/80216)).

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that in that moment, you have something/enough free RAM.
You could use tmpfs and work with file there, using sed.

I think that /path/to/file/filename is not big (they are just user environment file ).

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

Test it with `df -h /mnt/ramdisk` or `mount`, or `exit status code`

```
echo $?
0

df -h /tmp/tmpfs/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp/tmpfs
```

Now you can move or copy the file to /mnt/ramdisk and *do your stuff*, then replace original

More about [tmpfs or ramfs](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux) on jamescoyle site.