# Not enough disk space: remove first n lines of text file without copying the file

Tags: text-processing, tail, storage, text-formatting

I want to remove the first `$rmv` lines of a huge text file called `$filename`. This text file is so big that I cannot fit two copies of it on my hard drive.

The following leaves me with a blank file called `$filename`:

```
tail -n +$rmv "$filename" > "$filename"
```

The following cannot execute because I do not have the storage space to fit both `$filename` and `$filename.tmp`:

```
tail -n +$rmv "$filename" > "$filename.tmp" && mv "$filename.tmp" "$filename"
```

If it matters, I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `perl`:

```
{
  tail -n +"$rmi"
  perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'
} <file 1<>file
```

Note that with this approach, there's no backup of file, so any corruption makes you lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ed` does not use temp files, so

```
ed bigfile <<ED_SCRIPT
1,${rmv}d
w
q
ED_SCRIPT
```

Comment: It depends on whether you have sufficient memory to avoid the use of temp files, AFAIK.  But according to [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251024/135943), it always uses temp files in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

For scripted file edits, [the tool of choice is `ex`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269076/135943).

```
ex -sc "1,${rmv}d | x" "$filename"
```

You may also want to look into the [`split` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html).

Comment: So does `ed`.  `vi` at least doesn't seem to fail if the filesystem is full, but perhaps that's only true if the whole file can be held in memory.  I [ran into this before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250999/135943) and it's what started me on learning `ex`.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file is x MB, you do not have 2* x MB, but I suppose you do not have enough space to compress the file either? Text files often compress to a tenth of the original size...

You don't have enough space to hold just the ($total-$rmv) lines, but what if they are compressed? `tail -n +$rmv "$filename" | gzip > "$filename.tmp" && zcat "$filename.tmp" > "$filename"`

Taking this as an abstract intellectual problem, I would cut up the file in chunks, sized either to fit in memory or in available disk space, starting with the last chunk and then truncating the original file. I could also compress the file in place using `dd conv=notrunc` trickery.

However, in practice, I'd either

- copy the file over the network to a server with enough disk to hold (only) the ($total-$rmv) lines, check that I got the right lines, remove the original file, and copy back.
- add disk, since you obviously need it.

Comment: This site is NOT a "site for problems in a business environment".    It is for Unix and Linux questions in ANY environment including (but not limited to) business, educational/academic, non-profit, government, NGOs, and home.

Comment: @cas So I forgot I wasn't on ServerFault